# Ruby Shoes: using .click on an image cannot tell left from right click

Tags: ruby, click, right-click, shoes

I was trying to make an image that raises a number by one when left clicked and lowers it when right clicked.
I was able to make shoes detect which button is clicked with the below code:

```
Shoes.app do
  @info = para "No button pressed."
  click do |button|
    @info.replace "#{button} was PRESSED."
  end
end
```

And this works just fine. LMB is 1, RMB is 2, and MMB is 3.
But when I try and detect a clicked image

```
Shoes.app do
  number = 0
  @image = image "image.png"
  @info = para "No button pressed."
  @image.click do |button|
    @info.replace "#{button} was PRESSED."
  end
end
```

It seems to only be passing self. The result, regardless of button, is "(Shoes::Image) was pressed." I cannot find any way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you try this?

```
Shoes.app do
  number = 0
  @image = image "image.png"
  @info = para "No button pressed."
  @image.click do |button|
    @info.replace "#{button.inspect} was PRESSED."
  end
end
```

Comment: Still returns (Shoes::Image). I think the issue is in the "@image.click do |button|" part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

I think the click method of an element is designed to pass `self` as the block.

As far as I can see, the only way around it is to use the main click event and use the mouse position blocks to determine whether the mouse is over the image at the time of the click.

```
Shoes.app do
  number = 0
  @info = para "No button pressed."
  @image = image "image.png"

  click {|button, x, y|
    if (x > @image.left) && (x < (@image.left + @image.width)) && (y > @image.top) && (y < (@image.top + @image.height))
      @info.replace "#{button} was PRESSED."
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: I can get it to tell what's being clicked just fine. The issue is having the image tell left from right click. Normally "click do |button|" will return the button, but when used on an image it returns the image.

Comment: Have you tried that code? Right and left click on the image, it should change the `para` text. As far as I can tell, the only method that allows you to detect the button number is the main `click` method. So you need to separately compare the mouse and image positions to detect whether the image was clicked.